# Toggle Live Input Not Working Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, getusermedia

I have toggleLiveInput() function, and here's the problem:

I run the code, and it works fine on desktop. But when I build into an app (with Intel XDK in case you were wondering), it works as long as you've already launched the app once. The first time, it will completely ignore the function. It won't do it. Does anyone see why? Thanks!

```
function toggleLiveInput() {
    getUserMedia(
        {
            "audio": {
                "mandatory": {
                    "googEchoCancellation": "false",
                    "googAutoGainControl": "false",
                    "googNoiseSuppression": "false",
                    "googHighpassFilter": "false"
                },
                "optional": []
            },
        }, gotStream);
}
function gotStream(stream) {
    // Create an AudioNode from the stream.
    mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    // Connect it to the destination.
    analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = 2048;
    mediaStreamSource.connect( analyser );
    updatePitch();
    meter = createAudioMeter(audioContext);
    mediaStreamSource.connect(meter);
    drawLoop();
}
function drawLoop( time ) {
    rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame( drawLoop );
    volumeOfNote = meter.volume;
}
toggleLiveInput();
```

Edit: Just figured out something strange. I used `try() catch(e)` and no error was found. That means that the function is just being igonred. But for just one time? Strange...

Comment: Maybe if you added a second callback for failures, it would tell you what's wrong?

Comment: @jib I like where you're going wit this. What would the callback look like?

Comment: Add `, function(err) { console.log(err); }` after `gotStream`.

Comment: @jib I put it inside the function and it gives a syntax error. Where exactly should I place it?

Comment: @jib I showed it on the question

Comment: @jib Still a syntax error

Comment: Like this: `}, gotStream, function(err) { console.log(err); });`

Comment: @jib Thank you for your time. Unfortunately, there was no error... It didn't console/alert anything, which is odd.

Comment: @jib I edited the question so now you will see the entire process. What I am looking for is why it will not work only the first time on mobile.